# Passing a method as an argument in another method

Tags: c#

I want to pass a method as an argument to remove repetitive code from my program. This is the functionality I would like:

```
 private void sqlQuery(Method sqlMethod)
{
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        //open SQL connection
        conn.Open();
        sqlMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Using:

```
private void insertTemplate()
{
    //create SQL command
    SqlCommand insertTemplate = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [SavedDescriptionTemplates] (SavedDescription, UserId, CreatedDate) VALUES (@descriptionParam, @userIdParam, @createdDateParam)", conn);
    //create and assign parameters
    insertTemplate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriptionParam", descriptionInput.Text);
    insertTemplate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIdParam", Int32.Parse(userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value));
    insertTemplate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdDateParam", DateTime.Now);
    //execute command and retrieve primary key from the above insert and assign to variable
    insertTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The call would be:

```
sqlQuery(insertTemplate());
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate questions, we also have [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) available

Comment: Please consider wrapping your database code in a using block like using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){...}

Comment: Note you would be much better off defining your connection object as a local variable to `sqlQuery` and passing it as a parameter to your delegate, rather than making it an instance field and having other methods reference a connection that they don't know whether or not is open.  Then you'll want to use the `Action<SqlConnection>` delegate, not `Action`, and have `insertTemplate` accept the connection as a parameter.  This ensures that everywhere the connection can be accessed you *know* it's open.  Also can be combined with DOK's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a delegate.

Use for example [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
private void sqlQuery(Action action)
{
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        //open SQL connection
        conn.Open();

        action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate.

Change

```
private void sqlQuery(Method sqlMethod)
```

into

```
private void sqlQuery(Action sqlMethod)
```

and

```
sqlQuery(insertTemplate());
```

into

```
sqlQuery(insertTemplate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but slightly different...

Try this:

```
sqlQuery(insertTemplate); // don't CALL the method, just name it
```

And declare sqlQuery like this:

```
private void sqlQuery(Action sqlMethod)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). In your case, since your method takes no parameters, you can use the built in [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate:

```
private void sqlQuery(Action sqlMethod)
{
    //...
}

sqlQuery(insertTemplate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Blocks of logic in C# are passed as [*delegates*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are several ways of declaring a delegate - you can define a custom one, or use one of predefined types:

- You can use `Action<...>` for delegates that do not return values, or
- You can use `Func<...,R>` for delegates that return values.

Here is one way to define a function that takes a delegate:

```
private void sqlQuery(Action<IDbConnection> sqlMethod) {
   ...
   sqlMethod(conn);
   ...
}
```

Call `sqlQuery` with a named or an anonymous delegate which could be defined inline, as a named method, or as a lambda expression:

```
// Using some method that takes IDbConnection
sqlQuery(MySqlMethod);
// Using an anonymous delegate
sqlQuery((conn) => {
    ... // Do something with conn
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need to use delegates, anonymous functions, or lambda expressions.

Here's a simple example:

```
public void SomeMethod(Action<string> passedMethod)
{
    passedMethod("some string");
}

public void Caller()
{
    SomeMethod(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

If you run "Caller", it would output "some string".

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are the answer ->  [Microsoft on C# Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public void delegate MyDelegate();

MyDelegate del = this.insertTemplate;

private void sqlQuery(MyDelegate sqlMethod)
{
 ...
 del();
 ...
}
```